# 'gensim' is not defined even though it shows in the virtualenv packages

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gensim

I use virtualenv in Python. I use gensim in a script. I get this error
name 'gensim' is not defined
I tried to install genism using pip and conda. I ended up updating conda packages after some suggested solution .
I see there is genism 3.8 after reunnig pip list, but I still have the error !. Could you please tell me what to do
P.S. I take input from a html form in a Flask function. Inside the function, I call the script that has genism. The program show the forms input buttons . After clicking the submit buton, I get the error message.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

#database
import db
from db import *

# Gensim
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import preprocess_string, strip_punctuation, strip_numeric

# spacy for lemmatization
import spacy

# Plotting tools
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim  # don't skip this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#matplotlib inline

from conn import *
from functions import *

# Enable logging for gensim - optional
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the shortest possible code that triggers the error? (Is `import gensim` enough?) Can you show how you're launching that code, and the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "direct_topic_start.py", line 45, in <module>
    data_words=list(sent_to_words(data))
  File "C:\Users\saif\Desktop\flask-apps\functions.py", line 3, in sent_to_words
    yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))  # deacc=True removes punctuations
NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined

Comment: Can you show the shortest possible code that triggers the error? (Is `import gensim` enough?) How are you launching that code (from a file, from a notebook, using a specific interpreter, etc)?

Comment: Also, for formatted text like a multiline error message, it's much more helpful to add it to your question than put it in these unformatted comments. From what I can tell of the error you've reported in your comment, there are no lines of code shown shared with the 20 lines of code in your question. (If the code in the question isn't essential to triggering the error, it shouldn't be there. If there's other code, such as `data_words=list(sent_to_words(data))`, that is an essential part of triggering the error, it should be in the question.)